# Xamarin iOS and .Net Standard 2.0 Dependecy Service

Tags: ios, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm creating a new project using Xamarin and .net standard 2.0. My project has

> - **SLMobileLibrary**
> - **SLMobileLibrary.Android**
> - **SLMobileLibrary.iOS**

This three project are written to create a NuGet Package imported in another project:

> - **SLMobileLibraryTest**
> - **SLMobileLibraryTest.iOS**
> - **SLMobileLibraryTest.Android**

As you can see in this screen:

[image]

Now, SLMobileLibrary has a Dependecy Service:

```
using System;
namespace SLMobileLibrary
{
    public interface ISampleLibrary
    {
        string HelloWorld();
    }
}
```

SLMobileLibrary.Android has the implementation for Android:

```
using System;
using SLMobileLibrary.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SampleLibrary))]

    namespace SLMobileLibrary.Android
    {
        public class SampleLibrary : ISampleLibrary
        {
            public SampleLibrary()
            {
            }

            public string HelloWorld()
            {
                return "Hello World! Android";
            }
        }
    }
```

SLMobileLibrary.iOS has the implementation for iOS:

```
using System;
using SLMobileLibrary.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SampleLibrary))]
namespace SLMobileLibrary.iOS
{
    public class SampleLibrary : ISampleLibrary
    {
        public SampleLibrary()
        {
        }

        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World! iOS";
        }
    }
}
```

So, in my App.cs i recall the method in this way:

```
string t = DependencyService.Get<ISampleLibrary>().HelloWorld();
```

On Android I've no problem, on iOS the program crash with a null object exception, I think because It can't find the implementation on iOS. But, if I try to put SimpleLibrary.cs in SLMobileLibraryTest.iOS everything works great. I really can't understand why iOS can't find the implementation if the implementation is in SLMobileLibrary.iOS as SLMobileLibrary.Android.

Anyone can help me? I just attached the source code so you can download it and try to compile on iOS. ( https://drive.google.com/open?id=12P1zu7BUiwvAkelKAI7fsCxBJYqvmpwZ ).

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about a debug or release build?

Comment: For now everything is in Debug.

Comment: I checked your project and found ` SimpleLibrary.cs` already exist in `SLMobileLibraryTest.Android`..If I remove it , it throw the same exception .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot help you about the reason of this NRE but if you want to make it working it's enough that on iOS you remove the registration with `[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SampleLibrary))]` and you add `Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Register<SLMobileLibrary.iOS.SampleLibrary>();` just at the beginning of your `AppDelegate`.
Said this, in you I would try to use an IoC container like Autofac or MvvmLight, and constructor injection.

Comment: Ok, this solution works. Thanks you. I tried to do the .Register() into App.cs before the Get<> call and Xamarin give me an exception that say "Can find Default Constructor" or something like that, but interfaces doesn't had constructor. Btw I really can't understand why on it Works on Android and not on iOS, I will try to give a look at Autofac and MvvmLight.

Comment: You have to register in the AppDelegate, not in the App.cs, as you would do using an IoC container. This is equivalent to using the Dependency attribute.